# Are all reflections rotations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone prove to me why or why not all reflections are just rotations?

The only requirement on rotations is that it is a square matrix such that $R^T R = I$.

I tested this equation on a bunch of the reflection matrices here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_and_reflections_in_two_dimensions#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20two%2Ddimensional%20rotations,side%20of%20line%20L1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_and_reflections_in_two_dimensions#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20two%2Ddimensional%20rotations,side%20of%20line%20L1).

And they all seem to satisfy the rotation constraint.

So now I am not sure.

Comment: Also rotations have a determinant of $1$ and reflections have $-1$

Comment: "*The only requirement on rotations is that...*"  Citation needed.  You seem to have confused the words "*rotation*" with "*orthogonal matrix.*"  Rotations are a specific type of orthogonal matrix.  Not all orthogonal matrices are rotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit of a matter of definition. From my understanding, talking in terms of matrices, $R^T R = I$ defines an **orthogonal matrix** $R$. The word **rotation** is used, as J. W. Tanner commented, for orthogonal matrices for which det$(R) = 1$ (while $R^T R = I$ only required det$(R)^2 = 1$). When one wants to be super-specific with this, one sometimes uses the term of a **proper rotation** and allows for **improper rotations**, which only satisfy the weaker condition det$(R)^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a requirement for a real square matrix to be a rotation. You need that $R^T R = I$ *and* $det(R) = 1$. The matrix $ A =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} $ satisfies $A^T A = I$ but $det(A) = -1$. This is the matrix that reflects across the x-axis; it is not a rotation matrix.